# Speeding up find command?

Tags: linux

I need to find out huge files in the Linux server and where many people would be processing huge files and data loading will be happening. "find" command takes more time to give the output. Is there any other way to speed up the result of my command other than simplifying my search path?

Comment: Are these files with specific filenames or just big files in general ?

Comment: No, They don't have any specific names. It could be of any type. logs,text files etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dnotify`. You did not specify exactly what you want to do, so I cannot be more specific, but I will remark that the [dnotify Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dnotify) states:

> dnotify - Execute a command when the contents of a directory change

For instance, this command

```
 dnotify -CD -r /home/my_name -e echo change to {}
```

will print "change to " and then the name of the file changed, every time a file is created or deleted inside /home/my_name or any of its subdirectories.

You can couple this with a previously created list of existing files to keep a fully up-to-date list of files, to be read instead of running find.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache Lucene 4.6.0](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [ownCloud Server 5](http://owncloud.org/changelog/).

Apache Solr 4.6.0 for personal data fast-fulltext search.

Microsoft Windows freeware platform alternative: [SharePoint 2013 Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35488).

Answer (score 0):

1) man locate.

2) If you have relatively few, or not really important changes:  make a cache from your directory hierarchy with a find -type f intoa file. Once. Later you can grep in this file, which is much faster.

Comment: 1) My version of locate does not allow to filter result depending on size. 2) That means adding a crontab like `echo "0 0 * * * root find / -size +XXXXXX ... >/var/tmp/bigfiles.txt" > /etc/cron.d/find_bigfiles`

Comment: You have right, but your find can.